# Is homeomorphic image of closed bounded subsets of metric spaces , also closed bounded in the homeomorphic image metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X$ , $Y$ be homeomorphic metric spaces with homeomorphism $f$  , then is it true that for any closed bounded subset $A$ of $X$ , $f(A)$ is also closed and bounded in $Y$ ?

Comment: Hint: $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

No, boundedness of a metric space is not related to its topology. Indeed, let $(X,d)$ be an unbounded metric space. For $x,y \in X$ define $$d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}.$$
Then $(X,d')$ is a bounded metric space homeomorphic to $(X,d)$.

Answer (score 1):

The image of a bounded set need not be bounded. Consider the homeomorphism $\tan x\colon (-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to \mathbb R$. This homeomorphism maps the bounded set $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to the unbounded set $\mathbb R$. (By the way, both are closed in their respective topologies.)

On the other hand, if you replaced boundedness with *total* boundedness, and closedness with completeness, then the result is true.

**Proof:**

For a metric space $X$, a subspace $S\subset X$ is complete and totally bounded if and only if it is compact. Since the continuous image of a compact space is compact, it follows that $f(S)$ is compact as well, and therefore complete and totally bounded.

---

Suppose that both metric spaces are complete. Then we can recover the following version of your statement:

$$
\text{In a complete metric space, closed totally bounded sets are preserved under continuous maps. }
$$